# Project Euler - Number 2 - C#

Tags: c#, math

I'm quite new to programming in C#, and thought that attempting the Euler Problems would be a good idea as a starting foundation. However, I have gotten to a point where I can't seem to get the correct answer for Problem 2.

"Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:

1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...

By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms."

My code is this:

```
int i = 1;
int j = 2;
int sum = 0;

while (i < 4000000) 
{
     if (i < j)
     {
         i += j;

         if (i % 2 == 0)
         {
             sum += i;
         }

     }

     else
     {
         j += i;

         if (j % 2 == 0)
         {
             sum += j;
         }
     }
}

MessageBox.Show("The answer is " + sum);
```

Basically, I think that I am only getting the last two even numbers of the sequence and adding them - but I don't know how to get all of the even numbers of the sequence and add them. Could someone please help me, whilst trying to progress from my starting point?

P.S. - If there are any really bad layout choices, do say as eliminating these now will help me to become a better programmer in the future :)

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong.  I would suggest putting in debugging statements and then adding the output to your question.  Ex: Output i, j and sum after each loop.

Comment: For convenience: http://projecteuler.net/problem=2

Comment: Rechecked. 1) It's not an int overflow 2) You only check the end condition for every second element, but that's not the cause of your problem either.

Comment: You only test for i>4000000 at the top of the loop. But it is possible that i or j could exceed that after computing their next value, and that out of range value would then be added to sum. You should test for termination after computing the next new value, but before updating sum.

Comment: @hatchet While that's a bug, he was lucky enough that this specific cutoff didn't hit it, because the number that exceeded the limit was odd.

Comment: @Winneh - You might find this interesting, although it's a bit advanced -- http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/03/problem-2.html

Answer (score 3):

I just logged in into my Project Euler account, to see the correct answer. As others say, you forgot to add the initial term 2, **but otherwise your code is OK** (the correct answer is what your code outputs + 2), so well done!

It is pretty confusing though, I think it would look way clearer if you'd use 3 variables, something like:

```
int first = 1;
int second = 1;
int newTerm = 0;
int sum = 0;

while (newTerm <= 4000000) 
{
    newTerm = first + second;

    if (newTerm % 2 == 0)
    {
         sum += newTerm;
    }

    first = second;
    second = newTerm;
}

MessageBox.Show("The answer is " + sum);
```

Comment: Thank's very much! I really do appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the initial value of sum to 2, as you are not including that in your sum with the current code.

Also, although it may be less efficient memory-usage-wise, I would probably write the code something like this because IMO it's much more readable:

```
var fibonacci = new List<int>();

fibonacci.Add(1);
fibonacci.Add(2);

var curIndex = 1;

while(fibonacci[curIndex] + fibonacci[curIndex - 1] <= 4000000) {
    fibonacci.Add(fibonacci[curIndex] + fibonacci[curIndex - 1]);
    curIndex++;
}

var sum = fibonacci.Where(x => x % 2 == 0).Sum();
```

Comment: This solution does look a bit confusing as I don't actually understand LINQ. Would you suggest trying to go over LINQ as a foundation for C# sooner rather than later?

Thanks very much for your help, though!

Comment: LINQ isn't really that complex.  If you understand SQL it's basically just a C# version of SQL that I'm using to "query" a list in the above code (you can also use it against a number of other data sources besides in-memory lists).

Comment: However, I will say that if you're planning on doing more Project Euler problems, LINQ will come in *very* useful.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array `fib` to store the sequence. Its easier to code and debug. At every iteration, you just need to check if the value is even.

```
fib[i] = fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2];
if (fib[i] > 4000000) break;
if (fib[i] % 2 == 0) sum += fib[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this a few years ago, so I don't remember how I did it exactly, but I do have access to the forums talking about it.  A few hints and an outright solution. The numbers repeat in a pattern.  two odds followed by an even.  So you could skip numbers without necessarily doing the modulus operation.

A proposed C# solution is

```
        long sum = 0, i0, i1 = 1, i2 = 2;
        do
        {
            sum += i2;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                i0 = i1;
                i1 = i2;
                i2 = i1 + i0;
            }
        } while (i2 < 4000000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit ugly, since you're alternating between i and j. There is a much easier way to calculate fibonacci numbers by using three variables and keeping their meaning the same all the time.

One related bug is that you only check the end condition on every second iteration and in the wrong place. But you are lucky that the cutoff fit your bug(the number that went over the limit was odd), so this is not your problem.

Another bug is that you check with `<` instead of `<=`, but since there is no fibonacci number equal to the cutoff this doesn't cause your problem.

It's not an int overflow either.

What remains is that you forgot to look at the first two elements of the sequence. Only one of which is even, so you need to add `2` to your result.

```
int sum = 0; => int sum = 2;
```

Personally I'd write one function that returns the infinite fibonacci sequence and then filter and sum with Linq. `Fibonacci().TakeWhile(i=> i<=4000000).Where(i=>i%2==0).Sum()`

Answer (score 0):

I used a class to represent a FibonacciNumber, which i think makes the code more readable.

```
public class FibonacciNumber
{
    private readonly int first;
    private readonly int second;

    public FibonacciNumber()
    {
        this.first = 0;
        this.second = 1;
    }

    private FibonacciNumber(int first, int second)
    {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public int Number
    {
        get { return first + second; }
    }

    public FibonacciNumber Next
    {
        get
        {
            return new FibonacciNumber(this.second, this.Number);
        }
    }

    public bool IsMultipleOf2
    {
        get { return (this.Number % 2 == 0); }
    }
}
```

Perhaps it's a step too far but the end result is a function which reads quite nicely IMHO:

```
var current = new FibonacciNumber();
var result = 0;
while (current.Number <= max)
{
    if (current.IsMultipleOf2)
        result += current.Number;

    current = current.Next;
}
return result;
```

However it's not going to be as efficient as the other solutions which aren't newing up classes in a while loop. Depends on your requirements I guess, for me I just wanted to solve the problem and move on to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have solved this question, check it if its right.
My code is,

```
          #include<iostream.h>
          #include<conio.h>
          class euler2
            {
              unsigned long long int a;
             public:
            void evensum();
            };
         void euler2::evensum()
          {
             a=4000000;
             unsigned  long long int i;
             unsigned long long int u;

             unsigned long long int initial=0;
             unsigned long long  int initial1=1;
             unsigned long long int sum=0;
          for(i=1;i<=a;i++)
             {
                  u=initial+initial1;
                  initial=initial1;
                  initial1=u;
                if(u%2==0)
                   {

                 sum=sum+u;
                    }
               }
           cout<<"sum of even fibonacci numbers upto 400000 is"<<sum;
         }

             void main()
                 {
                    euler2 a;
                    clrscr();
                    a.evensum();
                    getch();
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my implementation:

```
public static int evenFibonachi(int n)
        {
            int EvenSum = 2, firstElem = 1, SecondElem = 2, SumElem=0;

            while (SumElem <= n)
            {
                swich(ref firstElem, ref SecondElem, ref SumElem);
                if (SumElem % 2 == 0)
                    EvenSum += SumElem;
            }

            return EvenSum;
        }

        private static void swich(ref int firstElem, ref int secondElem, ref int SumElem)
        {
            int temp = firstElem;
            firstElem = secondElem;
            secondElem += temp;
            SumElem = firstElem + secondElem;
        }
```